# How can I assign multiple values being returned from a subquery, one-by-one to each row in my main query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
netflix1=# \d+ rental
                                                                    Table "public.rental"
       Column       |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 rentalid           | numeric(16,0)                  |           | not null | nextval('rental_pk_sequence'::regclass) | main    |              |
 memberid           | numeric(12,0)                  |           | not null |                                         | main    |              |
 dvdid              | numeric(16,0)                  |           | not null |                                         | main    |              |
 rentalrequestdate  | timestamp(3) without time zone |           | not null |                                         | plain   |              |
 rentalshippeddate  | timestamp(3) without time zone |           |          |                                         | plain   |              |
 rentalreturneddate | timestamp(3) without time zone |           |          |                                         | plain   |              |
 dvd_copy_id        | numeric(10,0)                  |           |          |                                         | main    |              |
Indexes:
    "rental_rentalid_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rentalid)
    "rental_dvd_copy_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (dvd_copy_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "rental_dvdid_fk" FOREIGN KEY (dvdid) REFERENCES dvd(dvdid)
    "rental_memberid_fk" FOREIGN KEY (memberid) REFERENCES member(memberid)
Access method: heap
```

Another table:

```
netflix1=# \d+ dvd_copy
                                                          Table "public.dvd_copy"
   Column    |     Type      | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                    | Storage | Stats target | Description
-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 dvd_copy_id | integer       |           | not null | nextval('dvd_physical_copy_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 dvdid       | numeric(10,0) |           | not null |                                               | main    |              |
Indexes:
    "dvd_copy_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (dvd_copy_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "dvd_copy_dvdid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (dvdid) REFERENCES dvd(dvdid)
Access method: heap
```

I want to assign the column `dvd_copy_id` in rental its due values using `dvdid` as the common column in the two tables. However, `dvdid` is not unique in `dvd_copy` table and so I want something as following:

Say `dvdid`=4 has 5 counts in `dvdcopy` table, I want all the 5 values of `dvd_copy_id` corresponding to `dvdid` be assigned in the rental table.

Some data:
`dvd_copy`:

```
netflix1=# select * from dvd_copy;
 dvd_copy_id | dvdid
-------------+-------
           1 |     3
           2 |     1
           3 |     6
           4 |     7
           5 |     5
           6 |     2
           7 |     2
           8 |     4
           9 |     4
          10 |     4
          11 |     4
          12 |     4
(12 rows)
```

Some data from rental table:

```
netflix1=# select * from rental;
 rentalid | memberid | dvdid |  rentalrequestdate  |  rentalshippeddate  | rentalreturneddate  | dvd_copy_id
----------+----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------
        1 |        1 |     4 | 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 2019-02-09 00:00:00 |
        2 |        1 |     6 | 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 2019-02-09 00:00:00 |
        3 |        1 |     3 | 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 2019-02-09 00:00:00 |
        4 |        5 |     4 | 2019-02-15 00:00:00 | 2019-02-15 00:00:00 |                     |
        5 |        5 |     5 | 2019-02-15 00:00:00 | 2019-02-15 00:00:00 |                     |
        6 |       15 |     1 | 2019-02-12 00:00:00 | 2019-02-12 00:00:00 | 2019-02-21 00:00:00 |
        7 |        9 |     2 | 2019-02-19 00:00:00 | 2019-02-19 00:00:00 |                     |
        8 |        8 |     2 | 2019-02-20 00:00:00 | 2019-02-21 00:00:00 |                     |
        9 |        1 |     4 | 2019-02-20 00:00:00 | 2019-02-20 00:00:00 |                     |
       10 |       15 |     7 | 2019-02-28 00:00:00 |                     |                     |
       11 |        2 |     4 | 2004-02-02 00:00:00 |                     |                     |
       12 |        2 |     4 | 2004-02-03 00:00:00 |                     |                     |
(12 rows)
```

This is my query:

```
netflix1=# update rental set dvd_copy_id = (select dvd_copy_id from dvd_copy where dvdid=dvd_copy.dvdid)
;
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I understand that there should be a windowing function but I am unable to form one.

How do I assign `dvd_copy_id` values to each row in `rental` table?

Comment: Since there are multiple copies per dvd, which one do you want to assign to a given rental ? Or maybe you are looking to create new rental records? Please show us the result that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a single query. A window function won't help; the issue is one of data visibility.

Simply adding a `limit 1` to the subquery will not work because many rentals can get the same dvd_copy_id. Making the subquery something like `(select dvd_copy_id from dvd_copy where dvdid=dvd_copy.dvdid and not exists (select 1 from rental where dvd_copy_id=dvd_copy.dvdid) limit 1` also won't work because [every statement sees the database as it was when the statement started running](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html), so when the first row is `UPDATE`d with a dvd_copy_id, when the update gets to the next row, the `select 1 from rental where dvd_copy_id=dvd_copy.dvdid` will see `rental`'s rows without the newly-updated data, and you'll still get duplicate dvd_copy_ids.

The nature of what you're doing - where you need each `rental` row's dvd_copy_id to be influenced by modifications to the other `rental` rows - requires that you have at least one separate statement per modification that could be influenced by a previous `UPDATE`.

Practically speaking, I would handle this by putting together an UPDATE that worked for one row, duplicating it a bunch of times in a .txt, and piping it to psql. Yes, seriously. Ugly but works :)